# Create a JSON with unknown number of inputs in custom array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

```
while($ques = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    <input type='text' name='answers' test_id='".$ques['test_id']."' question_no ='[".$ques['question_no']."]'>
}
```

OUTPUT IS:

```
<input type='text' name='answers' test_id="1" question="1" >
<input type='text' name='answers' test_id="1" question="2" >
<input type='text' name='answers' test_id="1" question="3" >

<input type='text' name='answers' test_id="2" question="1" >
<input type='text' name='answers' test_id="2" question="2" >
<input type='text' name='answers' test_id="2" question="3" >
```

JAVA SCRIPT IS:

```
var frm = $('#test-set-form');
var data = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT IS:

```
[
    {"name":"answers","test_id":"1","question_no":"1",value":"<input value>"},
    {"name":"answers","test_id":"1","question_no":"2",value":"<input value>"},
    {"name":"answers","test_id":"1","question_no":"3",value":"<input value>"},

    {"name":"answers","test_id":"2","question_no":"1",value":"<input value>"},
    {"name":"answers","test_id":"2","question_no":"2",value":"<input value>"},
    {"name":"answers","test_id":"2","question_no":"3",value":"<input value>"},
]
```

I am create a JSON from inconstant number of inputs and send to the server and save each data to database. Some recommendation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please stop using *MySQL_functions* as they are deprecated and potentially unsafe. Use *MySqli* or *PDO*.

Comment: It is preferable to have unique NAME attributes within a form. Beyond that, it appears that you have a number of Tests and each test has a number of Questions, right? If so, the way of formatting the response JSON, imo, is in a de-normalized form. Basically,  in an object-oriented manner. So you have a number of classes (naming is up to you) that compose in the following way: TestingResponse -> TestAnswer[] -> (Test, Answer[] -> Question). Note the square brackets [] denoting multiplicity. E.g. { "tests": [{"test_id": 1, "answers": [{"question_id": 1,"value": "..."}, ...] }, ... ] }

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to change your form element `name` attributes to make use of arrays so you would have:

```
<input name="tests[the_test_id][questions][the_question_id]" />
```

So on the PHP side is $_POST this would look like:

```
Array(
    'tests' => Array(
        'the_test_id' => Array(
            'questions' => Array(
               'the_question_id' => 'the answer value'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

And then you could read it with something like:

```
foreach($_POST['tests'] as $test_id => $testData) {
    foreach ($testData['questions'] as $question_no => $answer) {
        // update the db using $test_id, $question_no, and $answer
    }
}
```

So the output of the elements would look like:

```
<?php 
     printf('<input type="text" name="tests[%s][questions][%s] />',
         $ques['test_id'],
         $ques['question_no']); ?>
```

By Doing this you can simply use use `$(selectorForTheForm).serialize()` on the from JS if you're doing ajax, or just use the default form submission process if you don't need ajax.

Of course if you really need it in JSON format for some reason then this isn't a good idea, but if you just need to POST the form (ajax or not) then this will work just fine.

If you really need it in JSON format then in addition to this you can add add data elements (simply because its easier and less error prone than trying to parse the data out of the `id` or `name` attribute) like:

```
<input name="tests[the_test_id][questions][the_question_id]" data-test_id="the_test_id" data-question_no="the_question_id" />
```

Which would make your output look something like:

```
<?php 
     printf('<input type="text" name="tests[%s][questions][%s] data-test_id="%s" data-question_no="%s"/>',
         $ques['test_id'],
         $ques['question_no'],
         $ques['test_id'],
         $ques['question_no']); ?>
```

So now on the JS side you could do:

```
var data = [],
    $inputs = $(selectorForTheInputs);

$inputs.each(function (){
    var $this = $(this),
        datum = $this.data();

    data.push($.extend({value: $this.val()}, datum));
});
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sbmejzdo/

Comment: Thank you :D I owe you so much. In php side, i am using the php 5.2 can you show me how to get each data in the version?

Answer (score 0):

I use smth like this:

```
while($ques = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    <input type='text' value=''
        name='"answers[{$ques['test_id']}][{$ques['question_no']}]"'>
}
```

out:

```
[
    { "key":"answers[1][1]", value":"" },
    { "key":"answers[1][2]", value":"" },
    //...
    { "key":"answers[5][15]", value":"" }
    //...
]
```

if you need to use only your notation, then parse html with js:

```
var $inputs = $('#form').find('input[name=answers]');
var data = [];

$inputs.each(function() {
    var attrsData = {};
    attrsData['name'] = $(this).attr('name');
    ...
    data.push(attrsData)
});
```

and you'll get what you want

```
$.ajax({
    data: data
    ...
})
```